# Accessing application context beans from thymeleaf email template

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have followed this Thymeleaf tutorial "[Rich HTML email in Spring with Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html)" to generate an email using a Thymeleaf template.
All is fine, but I can't access the ApplicationContext beans that I use elsewhere in the application.

To be more specific, in my email template I'd like to have something like:

```
<span th:text="${@myBean.doSomething()}">
```

where "myBean" is a @Component.
Is that possible at all?
I'm not looking for a workaround like

```
<span th:text="${myBean.doSomething()}">
```

where the bean is added as a variable in the template processing context.

The Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class MyWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
[....]
public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver resolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("emailtemplates/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine emailTemplateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.addTemplateResolver(emailTemplateResolver());
    engine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect()); // thymeleaf-layout-dialect
    addSpringSecurityDialect(engine); // thymeleaf-SpringSecurity-dialect
    return engine;
}
[....]
}
```

The email service:

```
@Service
public class MyEmailService {
@Resource SpringTemplateEngine emailTemplateEngine;
[....]
public boolean sendHtmlEmail(...) {
    final Context ctx = new Context(locale);
    ctx.setVariable("someVariable", "someValue"); // Don't want to add myBean here
    final String body = this.emailTemplateEngine.process("myTemplate", ctx);
    [....]
```

The Component:

```
@Component
public class MyBean {
    public String doSomething() {
        return "Something done!";
    }
}
```

The template:

```
<span th:text="${@myBean.doSomething()}">
```

The error:

> EL1057E:(pos 1): No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve
>   access to bean 'myBean'

I'm using thymeleaf-2.1.4 and spring-4.1.6

EDIT:

plese note that I can't use the HttpServletRequest because I send most of the emails in an @Async method where the request can't be reliably used. That's the reason why I use Context and not WebContext (although I didn't know about SpringWebContext - I guess that if somebody made that class for accessing beans via a "beans" variable, then using the @myBean notation must be something impossible).

Comment: Try to use SpringWebContext instead of Context.

Comment: SpringWebContext is a good suggestion, as it adds "A special beans variable of class (Beans) that allows users to access beans in the application context. This variable can be accessed like any other variable in the context: ${beans.myBean.doSomething()}." In my particulare case, though, I didn't mention that I also can't use the Request object because I'm sending emails in an @Async - updating the question now.

Comment: is making a custom context implementation an option? http://www.javased.com/?source_dir=thymeleaf-spring3/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/spring3/context/SpringWebContext.java

Comment: Yes a custom context would be an option! How do I add the parsing of "@" variables to the context?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's confusing because we have three different context here:

- The Spring `ApplicationContext`, which is not a `WebApplicationContext`, if we're sending a mail in a scheduled method.
- The Thymeleaf `org.thymeleaf.context.Context` on which you set/add variables.
- The SpEL evaluation context `org.springframework.expression.EvaluationContext`, used to evaluate SpEL expressions. For Thymeleaf that's the `ThymeleafEvaluationContext`.

If you don't have a Spring web context, all you need is to add the `ThymeleafEvaluationContext` with a reference to the application context as a variable to the Thymeleaf `Context`:

E.g. (in Kotlin)

```
@Service
class TemplateService(
        private val templateEngine: TemplateEngine,
        private val applicationContext: ApplicationContext
) {

    fun processTemplate(locale: Locale, template: String, vararg variables: Pair<String, Any?>): String {
        val context = Context(locale)

        // Set the Thymeleaf evaluation context to allow access to Spring beans with @beanName in SpEL expressions
        context.setVariable(ThymeleafEvaluationContext.THYMELEAF_EVALUATION_CONTEXT_CONTEXT_VARIABLE_NAME,
                ThymeleafEvaluationContext(applicationContext, null))

        // Set additional variables
        variables.forEach { (key, value) -> context.setVariable(key, value) }

        return templateEngine.process(template, context)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Found,
you need to add a bean resolver in your SpringWebContext. Bean Resolver is created by ThymeleafEvaluationContext.

```
    Map<String, Object> mergedModel = new HashMap<>();
    ConversionService conversionService = (ConversionService) this.request
            .getAttribute(ConversionService.class.getName()); // might be null!
    ThymeleafEvaluationContext evaluationContext = new ThymeleafEvaluationContext(this.ac,
            conversionService);
    mergedModel.put(ThymeleafEvaluationContext.THYMELEAF_EVALUATION_CONTEXT_CONTEXT_VARIABLE_NAME,
            evaluationContext);
    SpringWebContext ctx = new SpringWebContext(this.request, this.response,
            this.request.getServletContext(), this.request.getLocale(), mergedModel, this.ac);
```

Comment: new Beans(appContext) is automatically added in SpringWebContext constructor

Comment: @xtian no, if we don't have request/response, we can't use a SpringWebContext, you need to use a simple org.thymeleaf.context.Context.

Comment: Configuration to the Spring EL Context used by thymeleaf would be great and very useful here. I an now stuck because I cannot configure it and I am not in a web context.

Comment: Just adding the `ThymeleafEvaluationContext` (with the applicationConext and null as conversion service) as a variable to the `org.thymeleaf.context.Context` worked for us: `context.setVariable(ThymeleafEvaluationContext.THYMELEAF_EVALUATION_CONTEXT_CONTEXT_VARIABLE_NAME, new ThymeleafEvaluationContext(applicationContext, null))`. No web context or request/response necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the complete Context in themeleaf context

```
@Service
   public class MyEmailService {
   @Resource SpringTemplateEngine emailTemplateEngine;
   [....]
   public boolean sendHtmlEmail(...) {
       final Context ctx = new Context(locale);
      ctx.setVariable("beans", new Beans(appContext)); 
    final String body = this.emailTemplateEngine.process("myTemplate", ctx);
      [....]



<span th:text="${beans.myBean.doSomething()}">
```

The @ notation could be a problem, because if I understood it right, the templates a evaluated with spring el expression. May be it can be done, but will be time-consuming.

Comment: Nice code example but it did not work for me. What Beans class did you used? java.beans.Beans - has no such constructor.

Comment: hm, its some time ago. I think it was a self created class implementing Map-interface und on 'get' looking in the appContext for a bean the requestet name.