access spring bean into thymeleaf template outside controller
I use thymeleaf in spring to generate html, but outside controller like that:
@Service
class Generator(private val templateEngine: SpringTemplateEngine) {
   fun generate() : String = templateEngine.process("mytemplate",Context(null,null))
}

it is ok, but If I have a bean reference into the template like:
<p th:text="${@myBean.label}">Example</p>

Then the bean "myBean" is not found.
Note that it is found If the template is used into a controller:
@Controller
class MyController {
  @GetMapping("/test")
  fun generate()=ModelAndView("mytemplate")
}

What is the problem? Maybe I have to pass a special Context Object (containing the application context) to the template engine. I saw that there is a WebContext class but I don't know how the instanciate it. Is there any factory provided by spring?
Or maybe the problem is elsewhere??
The doc available is only about using thymeleaf into the controller...

Response found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244600/accessing-application-context-beans-from-thymeleaf-email-template?rq=2
